# iOS UITableView didn't reflect after reloadData:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

When press the plus icon, the current `navContorller` will present a new `navController` for adding new item.
When press the cancel, the app will delete the item added, and dismiss the new `navController` , and tableview will `reloadData`

When I tried to do `item.itemName = 75;` in `createItem` method, cancel button won't work, the tableview reloadData won't work.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

[image]

BNRItemsTableViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender
{
    // Create a new BNRItem and add it to the store
    BNRItem *newItem = [self.itemStore createItem];

    BNRDetailViewController *detailVC = [[BNRDetailViewController alloc] initForNewItem:YES];
    detailVC.item = newItem;
    detailVC.dismissBlock = ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"numberofrows is %ld", (long)[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]);
    };
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailVC];
    navController.restorationIdentifier = NSStringFromClass([navController class]);
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:navController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```

BNRDetailViewController.m

```
- (void)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] removeItem:self.item];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                      completion:self.dismissBlock];
}
```

BNRItemStore.m

```
- (BNRItem *)createItem
{
    double order;
    if ([self.allItems count]  == 0)
    {
        order = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        order = [[self.privateItems lastObject] orderingValue] + 1.0;
    }
    NSLog(@"Add after %lu items, order = %.2f", (unsigned long)[self.privateItems count], order);
    BNRItem *item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BNRItem"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    item.orderingValue = order;
    item.itemName = 75; // Comment this line would work OK.

    [self.privateItems addObject:item];
    if (item.valueInDollars > 50)
    {
        [self.itemGreaterThan50 addObject:item];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.itemLessThan50 addObject:item];
    }
    NSLog(@"after createItem: %ld", [self.itemGreaterThan50 count]);
    return item;
}

- (void)removeItem:(BNRItem *)item
{
    [self.privateItems removeObjectIdenticalTo:item];
    if (item.valueInDollars > 50)
    {
        [self.itemGreaterThan50 removeObjectIdenticalTo:item];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.itemLessThan50 removeObjectIdenticalTo:item];
    }
    [[BNRImageStore sharedStore] deleteImageForKey:item.itemKey];
    [self.context deleteObject:item];
}
```

Comment: You are not removing the item from the `dataSoure` of the first `UIViewController`. Your first tableView dataSource is *self.itemStore*. You are no where removing it on pressing cancel.

Comment: can u give me whole code of BNRDetailViewController.m?

Comment: @Rikh `self.itemStore` is singleton instance of `BNRItemStore`. I did `[self.privateItems removeObjectIdenticalTo:item]`, `[self.itemGreaterThan50 removeObjectIdenticalTo:item]`, and `[self.itemLessThan50 removeObjectIdenticalTo:item]` in `removeItem:` method from `BNRItemStore`. Can you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: Add to `BNRItemsTableViewController.m` a `viewDidAppear` method which calls `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: @vitormm tried it, no luck.